# Get package versions and dependencies without installing

Tags: python-3.x, package

I have a requirements.txt:

```
multiprocess
nltk
boosting
statsmodels
swifter
dask
catboost
spacy
seaborn
plotly
opencv
```

Notice it doesn't have versions for each package.

For each package, I want to get:

- the latest version
- its dependencies

How do I do this in Python (not in shell) **without** downloading or installing any of the packages?

Note: I have tried `johnnydep` package but it doesn't provide the data above if the package is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

To pull version and dependencies for single package:

```
import json
import urllib.request

def get_package_deps(package_name):
    url = f"https://pypi.org/pypi/{package_name}/json"
    data = json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
    info = data['info']
    version = info['version']
    dependencies = info['requires_dist']

    return version, dependencies

v, deps = get_package_deps('matplotlib')

print(v)
```

Returns:

`3.4.3`

To do this for all packages in reqs file, just iterate over the reqs file and call this function using `try-except` to avoid exceptions, including `HTTPError` and `NoneType`.